# Find index of collection over array

Tags: java

Im having this following loop

```
    for (Annotation currAnnotation : annotation.getAnnotations())
    {
        List<Map<String, String>> list = annotation.getList();
list.get(index)
```

the index should be the index of the loop,how can I achieve it ?
I need to get from the list the specific entry.

Thanks!

Comment: are you aware, you are not using the `currAnnotation` variable inside the loop, and thus could use the `getList()` method outside of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a counter:

```
int index = 0;
for (Annotation currAnnotation : annotation.getAnnotations())
{
    List<Map<String, String>> list = annotation.getList();
    ... list.get(index) ...
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know if there is a way to do that instead of define new varible

Comment: instead of using the enhanced `for` loop you can use the _normal_ `for` loop: `for (int index = 0; index < annotation.getAnnotations().size(); index++)`